# Java same variable has different values in different

Tags: java, libgdx

So I have a class which handles user input to a screen created as part of a libgdx application.
My problem is that the variable cameraDelta, which is a Vector2, appears to have a different value in keyTyped and getCameraDelta.

using a sys.out.println at runtime in both methods shows the value changing whenever any of 'wasd' are pressed, and the value stays over time, yet the value always stays at (0, 0) when outputted from getCameraDelta

```
public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {

    private Firetruck myTruck;
    private GameWorld myWorld;
    private int mouseX;
    private int mouseY;
    private Vector2 cameraDelta;

    public InputHandler(GameWorld myWorld) {
        this.myWorld = myWorld;
        myTruck = myWorld.getFiretruck();
        cameraDelta = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        if (character == 'w') {
            cameraDelta.add(0, 5);
        } else if (character == 's') {
            cameraDelta.add(0, -5);
        } else if (character == 'd') {
            cameraDelta.add(5, 0);
        } else if (character == 'a') {
            cameraDelta.add(-5, 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Vector2 getCameraDelta() {
        /*/
        Vector2 temp = this.cameraDelta.cpy();
        /*/
        Vector2 temp;
        temp = new Vector2(0, 0);
        temp.add(cameraDelta);
        Gdx.app.log("getCameraDelta", cameraDelta.toString());
        cameraDelta.x=0;
        cameraDelta.y=0;
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, why is `getCameraDelta` not just `Vector2 getCameraDelta() { return cameraDelta; }`? Either you compute it each time it's requested, or you have a private variable for it, but don't use both: that's just making things confusing for yourself. A really, a getter should not need to _modify_ the thing it's getting. That's called a side-effect, and code with side effects is code with bugs waiting to happen. If you want to return a copy, then use the copy constructor: `return new Vector2(cameraDelta)` and don't change the values in `cameraDelta`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I agree with that. Also, Unless the `InputHandler`'s new instance is created, the value for `Vector2` should not be changed to (0,0) unless changed manually. right?

Comment: initialising to some sane defaults is fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've changed the getter to simply a getter and added a call to zero it after it's used, however it hasn't fixed my problem that the value of the variable in keyTyped doesn't change the value in getCameraDelta from (0, 0), even though the value in keytyped doesn't get zeroed ever, it's like it's referencing two different variables

Comment: oops, it appears that the inputhandler was instantiated twice, with the first instance never saved and the second instance saved but not connected to the screen

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're adding in your new `Vector2` instance an object `cameraDelta`. Objects in java are passed by reference, so whenever you change something to your `cameraDelta` it will change everywhere where is used. For example :

```
public class Foo {
  public int fooNumber;
}

public class Bar {
  public Foo fooBar;

  public Bar() {
      fooBar = new Foo();
      fooBar.fooNumber = 1;
  }

  public void changeReference(Foo foo) {

      System.out.println(fooBar.fooNumber);  // RESULT -> 1

      fooBar = foo;  // here you're making your original foo to
      //point to the "foo" passed in the method

      foo.fooNumber = 0;

      System.out.println(fooBar.fooNumber); // RESULT -> 0
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Bar bar = new Bar();
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      bar.changeReference(foo);
      System.out.println(bar.fooBar.fooNumber); // RESULT -> 0
  }

}
```

Comment: So, in the case of the posted code in the Question, theses are the two "culprints": `cameraDelta.x=0;`, `cameraDelta.y=0;`

Comment: Yes, the `Foo` is the original `Vector2` and `fooNumber` the cameraDelta's `x` or `y`

Comment: While this makes sense, I'm not sure it's actually the problem I'm having. Printing the value of cameraDelta in the two functions yields this output: ```[keyTyped] (0.0,40.0)
[getCameraDelta] (0.0,0.0)
[keyTyped] (0.0,45.0)
[getCameraDelta] (0.0,0.0)
[keyTyped] (0.0,50.0)
[getCameraDelta] (0.0,0.0)
```

Comment: so the value in keyTyped isn't just being zeroed, it appears to be referencing an entirely different variable since it keeps it's value between being zeroed in calls to getCameraDelta

Comment: Look at your output : 
`[keyTyped]` is always a different from 0, while the `[getCameraDelta]` is always 0 because you're returning the `temp` variable which holds the `cameraDelta` object. Before your method returns `temp`, you set the `cameraDelta` values to x=0 and y=0, and because I've told you that java objects are passed by reference, once you make this `cameraDelta.x=0` , the `cameraDelta` from `temp` will change it's value too because it's the SAME reference in memory.